# RedirectResponse with FlashBag messages - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, session, flash-message

I'm trying to set a Flash message with RedirectResponse in my Authentication service for login.

```
public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return JsonResponse::create([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'callback' => 'Login.failed'
        ]);
    } else {
        $session = new Session();
        $session->getFlashBag()->set('error', $exception->getMessage());

        var_dump($session->getFlashBag()->all()); die; // Works here.

        return new RedirectResponse('/login');
    }
}
```

Twig:

```
{{ dump(app.session.flashbag.all) }}

{% for message in app.session.flashbag.get('error') %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ message|trans }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

No message in twig template...

I wonder, if redirectresponse flushes all flash messages?

Comment: I guess its due to creating a new instance of session you should get the existing instance of session and then set your flash messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony can't magically get all Session instances and use that. It only knows about instances that it created itself. Those live in the [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html). You should get the `session` service from this container and use that instead.

As you're probably inside a service, you should update your service definition with something like this:

```
services:
    your_service:
        class: ...
        arguments: ["@session"]
```

Now, update your class to save the session service in a property:

```
// ...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

// ...
class YourClassName
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }
}
```

Now, use the session instance saved in the property instead:

```
// ...
public function onAuthenticationFailure(...)
{
    // ...
    $this->session->getFlashBag()->set('error', ...);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: There is no need to inject @session to service. It works with new Session().

Comment: It doesn't, otherwise you didn't create this question?

Comment: @WouterJ although you are right and that is the solution, the `SessionInterface` type as parameter is improper, because it does not have a `getFlashBag()` method, it's just the native implementation of `Session` which is actually used, and for early error/fail reasons you should inject the correct type.

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan you create an object set something and then dump it. Of course it works it's the identical object! In twig you use the session from the service container which is not the same => inject the session

Comment: Thanks @Aitch. Looking a bit better at the code, I now indeed see that it's not part of the interface, but only of the implementation (which is quite ugly btw). I've updated the answer

Comment: Yeah I've also looked it up some time ago, because I thought what the hell has the flashbag to do with the session interface. fortunately it's not part, but some impl.-specific feature ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just I solved the problem. After calling the `{{ dump(app.session.flashbag.all) }}` your flashbag becomes empty.

Use once this code:

```
{% for message in app.session.flashbag.get('error') %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ message|trans }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Inspections "if ..." do not need or you do flashbag empty again, everything works as it should.